# Optimizing MySQL CREATE TABLE Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables I am trying to join in a third query and it seems to be taking far too long.

Here is the syntax I am using

```
CREATE TABLE active_users
(PRIMARY KEY ix_all (platform_id, login_year, login_month, person_id))
SELECT platform_id
    , YEAR(my_timestamp) AS login_year
    , MONTH(my_timestamp) AS login_month
    , person_id
    , COUNT(*) AS logins
FROM
    my_login_table
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;

CREATE TABLE active_alerts
(PRIMARY KEY ix_all (platform_id, alert_year, alert_month, person_id))
SELECT platform_id
    , YEAR(alert_datetime) AS alert_year
    , MONTH(alert_datetime) AS alert_month
    , person_id
    , COUNT(*) AS alerts
FROM 
    my_alert_table
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4;

CREATE TABLE all_data
(PRIMARY KEY ix_all (platform_id, theYear, theMonth, person_id))
SELECT a.platform_id
    , a.login_year AS theyear
    , a.login_month AS themonth
    , a.person_id
    , IFNULL(a.logins,0) AS logins
    , IFNULL(b.alerts,0) AS job_alerts
FROM
    active_users a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    active_alerts b
        ON a.platform_id = b.platform_id
        AND a.login_year = b.alert_year
        AND a.login_month = b.alert_month
        AND a.person_id = b.person_id;
```

The first table (logins) returns about half a million rows and takes less than 1 minute, the second table (alerts) returns about 200k rows and takes less than 1 minute.

If I run just the SELECT part of the third statement it runs in a few seconds, however as soon as I run it with the CREATE TABLE syntax it takes more than 30 minutes.

I have tried different types of indexes than a primary key, such as UNIQUE or INDEX as well as no key at all, but that doesn't seem to make much difference.

Is there something I can do to speed up the creation / insertion of this table?

EDIT:
Here is the output of the show create table statements

```
CREATE TABLE `active_users` (
  `platform_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `login_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `logins` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `ix_all` (`platform_id`,`login_year`,`login_month`,`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci

CREATE TABLE `alerts` (
  `platform_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alert_year` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `alert_month` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_id` char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `alerts` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `ix_all` (`platform_id`,`alert_year`,`alert_month`,`person_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

and the output of the EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra

1   SIMPLE  a   (null)  ALL (null)  (null)  (null)  (null)  503504  100 (null)

1   SIMPLE  b   (null)  ALL ix_all  (null)  (null)  (null)  220187  100 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Comment: "Is there something I can do to speed up the creation / insertion of this table?" Yes run it on a SSD disk because these statements will max out (random) disk I/O to copy between tables, in worst cause the temporary table also have to be created first to group the data in which also can be disk based I/O if the temporary table does not fit in the memory

Comment: Thanks - the server is running on SSD, I have tried creating all / some of the tables as temporary tables to no real effect.

Comment: "the server is running on SSD" Really 30 minutes to run on SSD when there really must be wrong assuming the indexes are correct.. For a better answer about performance you should provide the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` output for every table imvolved in the question and provide the `EXPLAIN` output for every SELECT part in the question.

Comment: Thank you - here is the output of the show create table statements

Comment: [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54944956/edit) the question with the information..

Comment: Just FYI it is running on Amazon RDS, General Purpose SSD

Comment: now i see i didn't notice before the `LEFT JOIN` didn't had a (limiting) filter and needed to check everything.. the `EXPLAIN` tells me it's using two FULL table scans and is using a nested loop (`Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`) to match the records meaning it's needs to look into a estimated off `503504  * 220187 = 110865035248 records`.. That totally explained the 30 minutes+ runtime so your query is far away from optimal.

Comment: Thank you - do you have any idea how I could optimise it?

Comment: How about an [ANALYZE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/analyze-table.html) of the first 2 before using them for the 3th? But for the 3th, a create & insert might be better.

Comment: i doubt that will work @LukStorms, also the table is then **read locked** for InnoDB and MyISAM

Comment: You could try rewritting the query into using a `UNION ALL` approach.. And use a `INNER JOIN` in the first select. and  a `NOT IN()` method in the second to replace the `LEFT JOIN` more or less like ..  `WHERE (a.platform_id, ....) NOT IN (SELECT platform_id, ...)` .. but i doubt this will scale correctly because `IN()` and `NOT IN()` tends to optimize also badly with a large results within them

Comment: I see `Using where` in the EXPLAIN. Why is there no WHERE clause in your query?

Comment: @RaymondNijland - could you please add your comments as an answer? I found the answer myself but couldn't do it without those comments....

Comment: "I see Using where in the EXPLAIN. Why is there no WHERE clause in your query?" @PaulSpiegel because MySQL optimizer adds a `WHERE` clause see [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2qFMEuwcNHm9NJkoz1M7iN/0) ,  notice the `WHERE 1` in the explain rewrite handling.

Comment: @RaymondNijland - Thx for info. Though `WHERE 1` from optimizer still doesn't make sense to me - It's just confusing. But.. In the warning I see `test.a.person_id = convert(test.b.person_id using utf8mb4)`. Because of this conversion the index cannot be used. The fix should be to explicitly define all columns in the temp tables and use the same data types.

Comment: "The fix should be to explicitly define all columns in the temp tables and use the same data types." Well almost true @PaulSpiegel one table `alerts` defines `person_id char(36) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL` i also didn't noticed it before.. Just remove the `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin`   in the source table.

Comment: "Thx for info. Though WHERE 1 from optimizer still doesn't make sense to me - It's just confusing" indeed it's wierd @PaulSpiegel maybe it's used in the execution part as a flag to select all matching records.. Because `WHERE 1` matches all and always true.

Comment: In first instance the data type for `person_id` and collation should be the same in `my_login_table` and `my_alert_table`. Even better if it would be INT or at least BIGINT. But that might be too late for a change on two huge tables.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but I figured out how to get it to run much faster.

I added a primary key to the third table on platform, year, month, person

I inserted the intersect data using an inner join, then insert ignore the left table plus a zero for alerts in a separate statement.